# How can I change a scrolling menubar to a stable one?

Tags: html, css, scroll, menubar

I am creating a website and I wanted to have scrolling menubar at first and then I realised that it does not appear on every browser, now I want to change it to a stable menubar. What would be the best way to convert a scrolling menu bar to a stable one?

```css
.menubar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin-top: -80px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(200, 155, 155, 0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(200, 155, 155, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(200, 155, 155, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar" data-scroll="true">
  <ul class="mainmenu">
      <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide your css and html so we can help you!

Comment: We need your code to fix your problem

Comment: I just added some part of the code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

try change this

```
<div class="menubar" data-scroll="true">
```

to

```
<div class="menubar">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately when i tried that, the menubar disappeared

Comment: did you apply any style to 'mainmenu' ?

Comment: Yes i did apply style on mainmenu.